# No Internet connection in Android-x86 4.2 ISO on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, android, iso-image

I installed Oracle VirtualBox on Windows 8. Then I downloaded `android-x86-4.2-20121225.iso` from [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/).

After I installed Android x86-4.2 on VirtualBox from the ISO, I could run it, but the Internet is not working.

What can I do to troubleshoot this or get Internet connectivity?

Update:- 
(1) I try it In VB, changing NAT connection settings to: **AMD PCNet FAST III (Am79C973)** but still not working

(2) I use other OS like **windows XP with NAT connection settings to: AMD PCNet FAST III (Am79C973) setting that work nice like internet and everything**. so plz give me a other option for android-x86-4.2-20121225 to connect internet ??

Answer (score 3):

In VB, try changing NAT connection settings to:

```
AMD PCNet FAST III
```

The Intel settings don't ever work for me.

### To change it:

1. Select the Virtual Machine from the list.
2. Click the gear icon labeled *Settings*.
3. In the window that opened, select the tab *Network*.
4. Make sure adapter one is enabled by ticking the box at the top.
5. At the drop down menu *Attached to*, select *NAT*.
6. Click the small blue arrow with the label *Advanced* if not already done.
7. Change the *Adapter Type* to `AMD PCNet FAST III (Am79C973)`
8. Hit *Okay* and run the virtual machine again.

[image]

Comment: Well this didn't work for me , in WIndows 8 Oracle VM 4.3 for 4.4kitkat image. :-(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For android kitkat 4.4 enable nat for network adapter and "Paravirtualized Network(virtio-net)" for the adapter type.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before.
I recommend you use **Bridged Adapter**
and select the NIC that **is** part of your pc/laptop

In the virtual Android it will not show up but you will be able to browse and access the app store.
You will need to change the settings inside of the Android OS to allow big files to be downloaded regardless of the network it want you to use by default, otherwise, for example, large games will not install.

Virtualbox Android 4.4 Network settings:

[image]

Comment: "You will need to change the settings inside of the Android OS to allow big files to be downloaded regardless of the network it want you to use by default" Where/which setting should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Select NAT and Paravirtualized in networks setting and then Virtwifi when setting up the android device.