# GoToMeeting in Android x86 tells me that there's no internet - but there is

Tags: networking, virtualbox, android, gotomeeting

Following the instructions in this answer:

[No Internet connection in Android-x86 4.2 ISO on VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/618886/no-internet-connection-in-android-x86-4-2-iso-on-virtualbox)

I managed to get Android x86 running in a VirtualBox VM connected to the outside world. Webbrowsers can access the net, so can the Google Store. Strangely, I have trouble with one particular app, GoToMeeting. It keep telling me there is no internet - which is also what Android keeps telling me on its home screen.

I suspect that GoToMeeting is looking for a wireless network or an LTE connection, which does not exist. Any idea how to debug or handle this problem?

Comment: Contact GoToMeeting support explain the situation.  If it is looking for a mobile wireless connection then only they can fix the application.

Comment: @Ramhound Done, waiting for an answer. I am not sure what the app is looking for. Actually, Android is also falsely telling me that there is no network although it is connected. So the limiting factor could be an API call into Android which returns "no internet". I was thinking about defining an alias that makes the "tethered" connection look like a wireless one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android x86 is not supported by GoToMeeting. An ARM-based system is required.

More details can be found here: https://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/the-gotomeeting-app-in-android-x86-tell-me-that-theres-no-internet-but-there-is?rfm=1